# SharePoint MySite Site Collection not creating for ADFS Users

Tags: 2016, site-collection, adfs, mysite, onedrive

I have the following Problem:
MySite is working fine with User authenticating through NTLM, but now I've changed the configuration, so only ADFS authentication is enabled. 
The Problem is now, that MySite is opening, but the Site Collection for each user will not create and OneDrive stucks in the initial configuration. In the ULS Logs I can see

> "401 UNAUTHORIZED".

I'm using SharePoint 2016 with August 2018 CU.

Can someone here help?

EDIT:

More Infos of the ULS:

> MySiteSyncProvisioningManager:CanStartMySiteCreation: Site master not found or invalid. Skipping sync provisioning for User:'i:05.t|adfs|*********'. Content database: [*********]
>   PartitionId: ********. Loaded from user data = True. Delay loading additional properties, triggered by property UserName

Comment: Did you configure ADFS with Kerberos or SAML?

Comment: ADFS was configured with SAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a sharepoint bug, after activating, NTML authentication again and configure people picker to only show ADFS Users everything works fine!